# Sticky Nav 'bounces' in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am developing a website that has a navigation bar about 600 pixels from the top of the screen. When the user scrolls past the nav bar, I have a javascript function that changes the class to make the position:fixed. It works well in all browsers except in Internet explorer. In IE it bounces each time the user scrolls.

Nav Bar

```
  <div class="w-container navbox">
    <a class="w-nav-brand moblielogo" href="#homeScroll"><img class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-large" src="images/logo_2015.png" alt="moblie nav Logo"/>
    </a>
    <nav class="w-nav-menu w-clearfix" role="navigation">
        <a class="w-nav-link leftnavlink moblienavlink"  href="#homeScroll">Home</a>
        <a class="w-nav-link leftnavlink moblienavlink" href="#companieScroll">Companies</a>
        <a class="w-nav-link leftnavlink moblienavlink"  href="#contactScroll">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="w-nav-button">
      <div class="w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 805) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('stickynav');
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('stickynav');
        }
    });


</script>
```

CSS

```
.stickynav {
position:fixed;
top:0;

}
```

What I think is going wrong is that IE is removing and adding this class each time this function is called. But I'm not sure how to test this or fix it.

Made a simplified version on jsfiddle
[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/cetm5frn/)

Comment: Is there a test link or jsfiddle link to see the working code ?

Comment: @Gurkanat yep. was creating it. see edits above.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with ie 11 and it doesn't bounce when i scroll. May be you can use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` meta tag for different versions of ie.